# Stoping a function in a node server from the front-end

Tags: node.js

I am building this app where each user can execute a function in my node.js server, the function is a loop that keep running and updating the db. My goal is to find a way to stop the function executed by the user, to give you an idea about the logic I already implemented please see the code below :

```
app.get('/api/v1/', cors(), (request, response) => {
    let timer = setInterval(apiCall, interval);
    if (request.query.running === false) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    function apiCall(i) {
        webshot(url, 'public/' + filename, options, function (err) {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
        });
    }
})
```

I was planning to send an API call with running=false to stop it but it doesn't seems to work, it just create another thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works, with a few improvements and changes in logic:

- You should compare to 'false' instead of false, or parse/eval the
  querystring.
- Your `timer` variable's scope should be the entire web process. If you declare it inside the function, you loose its reference to use it later in `clearInterval`.
- Your `setInterval` must be inside an else clause, in other way you'll be cancelling it and starting it again in the same call.
- Your example didn't have defined the `interval` variable. I changed it for 2s.

Having this changed, your example works. Check it out:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var timer;

function apiCall(i) {
  console.log("api called " + Date());
}

app.get('/api/v1/', (request, response) => {
    if (request.query.running === 'false') {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log('Timer stopped');
    } else {
      console.log('Timer started');
      timer = setInterval(apiCall, 2000);
    }
    response.send(200);
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Of course this solution has a problem: it will not distinguish between user calls: this means that if several users call your API endpoint, all of them will be interacting with the same timer. If you want different timers per user you'll have to add logic inside your api to detect which user made the call, and of course have a different timer for each user. The easiest would be to add a name inside the API call: `/api/v1/john/`, and instead of a `timer` variable, have a mapping with the timer variable for each user. Regards!

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is true that I should treat false as a string, I also like the idea of adding the user to the path, dat way I can target specific endpoints